# spring-data-mongo - optional query parameters?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data mongo with the JSON based query methods, and am unsure how to allow optional parameters in a search query.

For instance - say I had the following function

```
@Query("{ 'name' : {$regex : ?0, $options : 'i'}, 'createdDate' : {$gte : ?1, $lt : ?2 }} }")
List<MyItem> getItemsLikeNameByDateRange(String name, Date startDateRange, Date endDateRange);
```

-but I didnt want to apply the name regex match, or not apply a date range restriction if NULL values were passed to the method.

At the moment it looks like I might have to build the query using the mongoTemplate.

Are there any alternatives - or is using mongoTemplate the best option?

Thanks

Comment: For now I have gone down the route of using the Criteria classes.  It does seem a lot cleaner than embedding JSON queries in annotations, and easier to customize which fields are retrieved.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To implement this in Boolean logic I do the following and the conversion to operations that are available in programming languages

```
:query != null -> field == :query
!(:query != null) || (field == :query)
(:query == null) || (field == :query)
```

In plain SQL, this is done as

```
where (null = :query) or (field = :query)
```

In MongoDB this is done through the $where

```
{ $where: '?0 == null || this.field == ?0' }
```

We can speed this up *a little* by using Mongo Operations rather than building everything to the function at the expense of some readability. does not work unfortunately.

```
{ $or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { field : ?0 } ] }
```

So what you have is

```
@Query("{ $or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { field : ?0 } ] }")
List<Something> findAll(String query, Pageable pageable);
```

This can be further expanded to handle arrays for in/all clauses

```
@Query("{ $or : [ { $where: '?0.length == 0' } , { field : { $in : ?0 } } ] }")
List<Something> findAll(String query, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: If your query parameter is of type Date you have to write the $where part like this to work:

`{ $where: '\\'?0\\' == \\'null\\'' }`

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for Page results, because $where is not allowed in the count command. I had to write a custom query method to get the number of the matched documents.

Comment: In addition to @RaresOltean: as '$where' evaluates JS it might be handy to use string comparison as default. 
In may case i had a dash in the name which the JS interpreter took as a minus and blow up.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Archimedes's answer:
If you need the count of matched documents, replace `$where` with `$expr`.

```
@Query("{ $or : [ { $expr: { $eq: ['?0', 'null'] } } , { field : ?0 } ] }")
Page<Something> findAll(String query, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering out parts of the query depending on the input value is not directly supported. Nevertheless it can be done using `@Query` the `$and` and operator and a bit of [SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions).

```
interface Repo extends CrudRepository<MyItem,...> {

  @Query("""
         { $and : [ 
            ?#{T(com.example.Repo.QueryUtil).ifPresent([0], 'name')}, 
            ?#{T(com.example.Repo.QueryUtil).ifDateBetween([1], [2], 'startDate')},
            ... 
         ]}
         """)
  Page<MyItem> findDataSearchParams(String name, String city, ...)

  class QueryUtil {
    public static Document ifPresent(Object value, String property) {
      if(value == null) {
        return new Document("$expr", true); // always true
      }
      return new Document(property, value); // eq match
    }

    public static Document ifDateBetween(Object value1, Object value2, String property) {
      // ...
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Instead of addressing the target function via the `T(...)` *Type* expression writing an `EvaluationContextExtension` (see: [json spel](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-spel) for details) allows to get rid of repeating the type name over and over again.