# Spring Data MongoDB AND/OR query with multiple optional parameters

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I'm trying to execute a query with more than 2 optional parameters but I don't get any result. For the 2 parameters I followed the answer of this question [spring-data-mongo - optional query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613464/spring-data-mongo-optional-query-parameters).

So for example, with the following query everything is ok:

```
@Query("{$and: [{$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { a : ?0 } ]}, {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]}]}")
```

But if I add one more parameter it stops to work:

```
@Query("{ $and : [{$and: [{$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { a : ?0 } ]}, {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]}]},{$or : [ { $where: '?2 == null' } , { c : ?2 }]}]}")
```

I triple checked the syntax and seems ok, but I get empty results (even if I'm sure I should obtain at least few documents).

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you try carefully hand-format you query to be more readable, you will note that you have made a few mistakes with the closing brackets.

Try this query instead:

```
{ $and : 
    [{
       $and: 
        [
         {$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { a : ?0 }]}, 
         {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]},
         {$or : [ { $where: '?2 == null' } , { c : ?2 }]}
        ]
    }]
}
```

---

Side note: I think one `$and` will be enough, i.e. remove the top-level `$and` operator.

Comment: Thk! I didn't know $and operator could work with more than 2 elements. It works and it is more readable too :-)

Comment: Is there a way to use $regex here ? Because I couldn't make it work