# Spring Data MongoDB query with multiple optional parameters $in Collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I have a use case where my query need to find based on 3 optional fields and one of them is pass in as a collection.

The "3 optional fields" part is already solved by this post
[Spring Data MongoDB AND/OR query with multiple optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25047673/spring-data-mongodb-and-or-query-with-multiple-optional-parameters)

However, I am runnig into the issue with the `$in` for the collection filed.

For example, in the following query

```
{ $and : 
    [{
       $and: 
        [
         {$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { a : ?0 }]}, 
         {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]},
         {$or : [ { $where: '?2 == null' } , { c : ?2 }]}
        ]
    }]
}
```

In my case, the field `a` is actually pass in as a collection, I need to find those object in MongoDB with filed `a` is `$in` the collection I passed in.

I have tried with something like this

```
 { $and : 
        [{
           $and: 
            [
             {$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { a : { $in : ?0 }}]}, 
             {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]},
             {$or : [ { $where: '?2 == null' } , { c : ?2 }]}
            ]
        }]
    }
```

However, I got NPE for this when I pass in a `null` collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the collection length, as shown here [spring-data-mongo - optional query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12164989)
You can also get rid of the top-level *$and*.

```
{ $and : 
       [
        {$or : [ { $where: '?0.length == 0' } , { a : { $in : ?0 }}]}, 
        {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]},
        {$or : [ { $where: '?2 == null' } , { c : ?2 }]}
       ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't use $in for optional list parameter because when not specified it will be null and $in accept only list. To do that You will have add [] around optional list parameter and then flatten this list like that:

```
{ $and : 
   [
    {$or : [ { $where: '?0 == null;' },
             { $where: '[].concat.apply([],[?0]).indexOf(this.a) !== -1;'}]}, 
    {$or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { b : ?1 }]},
    {$or : [ { $where: '?2 == null' } , { c : ?2 }]}
   ]
}
```

use that for mongo version < 3.4 and since 3.4 You can use `includes` function instead of `indexOf`