# Spring data mongodb: Optional @Query parameter no longer works

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

After upgrading to spring data mongodb 1.10.1, I am getting errors when running queries like:

```
@Query("{$and :["
            + "{ $or : [ { $where: '?0 == null' } , { 'field1' : ?0 } ] },"
            + "{ $or : [ { $where: '?1 == null' } , { 'field2' : ?1 } ] },"
            + "]}")
public Page<Entity> findAll(String param1, String param2)
```

Checking the error I see the parameter inside the where clause is not quoted and as I result I get:

> org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Query
>   failed with error code 139 and error message 'ReferenceError:
>   test_param_value is not defined :

I have seen a few answers here recommending this way of handling optional parameters (([spring-data-mongo - optional query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613464/spring-data-mongo-optional-query-parameters))) but it no longer works and I cannot seem to find anything in the release change log.

Comment: it does not know what type is ?0 or ?1, it can't compare undefined == null because it can't figure out what is undefined. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case anyone else is interested, I managed to find a workaround after checking a similar [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1565) int the Spring Data project.

It seems the way I was checking for null parameters in the query is not a good practice. This is from a Spring developer comment: "placeholders are not designed to compose keys/values but bind parameters. Beyond that, placeholder use in quoted strings is always problematic in terms of escaping. Using SpEL should suit your needs"

So I ended up using SpEL to do the checks on parameters and it works fine. This is how it looks:

```
@Query("{$and :[" 
        + "?#{ [0] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'field1' : [0] } },"
        + "?#{ [1] == null ? { $where : 'true'} : { 'field2' : [1] } },"
        + "]}")
public Page<Entity> findAll(String param1, String param2, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Doesn't the usage of $where affect performance? Since it will execute js on each document https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where

Comment: It does not work to me with Pageable, I mean it returns '$where is not allowed in this context'

Comment: In my case the parameters where String.Empty so the null validation didn't work. Using this validation [0].length == 0 did the trick for me.

Comment: For the '$where is not allowed in this context' error, use $expr instead.